# Is it okay to run node apps on AWS instance using `node app.js`

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-ec2

I am running node apps on my local machine using the command 
`node app.js` from the directory of the application.

Is it okay to do the same on an AWS instance as well without packing the application? Just run it as I did on the local machine and then opening the port to the public.

Are there any security issues to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask whether it's OK deploy a node app (on an AWS instance) by, I guess,

- cloning and/or pulling your source code to a directory,
- running `npm install`
- running `node app.js`

Yes, it's OK. But it's not the best of practice.  What could go wrong?

- If you do this in a shell, and then close the shell, your node app will stop.
- To be secure on the public net, you want https to serve your app. You can build your node app using an `https` server and run it. But then you're making node do the crypto work.
- If your AWS instance reboots (that happens sometimes) your node app won't be running afterward.

If you're going into production, you're better off:

- rigging an `nginx` reverse proxy on your to handle the https and forward requests to node.
- using a decent deployment scheme for your node app. There are several, and your favorite search engine will find them for you.

Does this way of deploying an app present any security issues?

1. It certainly has any security issues your app.js already contains.
2. You're probably running your shell with your own username, with development privileges (access to git, for example). A deployed app on the public web should run with from a directory structure containing only what's necessary to make it work, and with a user and group dedicated to the purpose.  On Linux servers, the user you want is often `www-data`.

Comment: Thanks!.. Much appreciated.